# Mongodb group & match not working together in cosmos db mongo api

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, azure-cosmosdb

Given the document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f0179f9b62f038ec8f65dd"),
    "WebFormPath" : "www.testing1.com",
    "OwnerId" : "1234",
    "LastUpdatedOn" : ISODate("2017-10-25T04:48:31.606Z")
}
```

How to do a group by and fetch only where count > N.

Using the below query isn't returning any result. Can any one point out what is missing here?

```
db.getCollection('personalblacklist').aggregate([{'$group':
{'_id': {'WebFormPath': '$WebFormPath'},'count': {'$sum': 1}}},
{'$match': {'count':{'$gte':2}}}])
```

Thanks

Comment: Your aggregation should return the expected result. Could you make sure 1) you're using the correct database/collection 2) there are count results that are greater or equal to 2. i.e. you can remove `$match` stage to debug.

Comment: 1) yes, 2) yes, 3) does provide result with expected count after removing the match. It is just that match isn't working as second step of pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

$match is currently supported as the first aggregation stage only, that's why there's no results.

Comment: can you please point to a msdn or azure documentation where it is mentioned.

Comment: Do we have any update on when the $match will be available post $group as well? i.e. as second pipeline step.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right venue to make roadmap announcements, but we will update through Azure User Voice or Azure blog about this. Also docs will be updated to reflect the limitation